# AWS S3: can't list the bucket after change of policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We have created a Bucket in AWS S3 and a IAM-User with a specific policy to restrict the access to this bucket as follows:

**Bucket**: testbucket

**Policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then we've created a IAM-User and assigned this policy to the permissions of the user. We got an Access-Key and a Secret-Access-Key and can successfully upload files to the bucket and also download them with a given, known URL to the resources.

Now we want be able to also List all objects in the bucket.
Therefor i have changed the policy this way:

**New Policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The new item here is `s3:ListBucket`.

I have changed this policy successfully and can reload the page on AWS to ensure that these changes are still existing.

However, i've already waited for a hour but i am still unable to list the objects of the bucket.

For testing i use the app CyberDuck. It can list the bucket itself after authentication but it still can't list the objects in the bucket.

Do i need to do something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

s3:ListBucket applies to the bucket, not to the objects within it. Therefore, the second statement must not have the trailing slash and wildcard and so should be:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket"
    ]
}
```